# Best Python API for formula based Spreadsheet?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

My requirement is to fetch the data out of Spreadsheet(.xlsx) by inputting values in some cells .

On inputting value, other formula cells must have the calculated values based on the formula embedded in the sheet.

lets say I am inputting values in Cell A and B . C is a formula cell =A+B .

SO need to get the value in C and also other formula cells.

Had written following code in python 3.

```
import openpyxl as op
new_excel = op.load_workbook('WorkBook1.xlsx',read_only=False)
spreadsheet = new_excel .get_sheet_by_name('Input Quote')
spreadsheet['B30'] = 'VAU'
spreadsheet['D30'] = 1000
spreadsheet['F30'] = 5000

new_excel.save('WorkBook2.xlsx')#saving in a new file as I need to maintain versions

loa_excel1 = op.load_workbook('WorkBook2.xlsx',data_only='TRUE')#Opening the new file
spreadsheet1 = loa_excel1.get_sheet_by_name('Input Quote')
print(spreadsheet1['J13'].value)
# Output is None
```

J13 is a formula Cell that has dependency on B30,D30 and F30(inputted values).

How can we achieve this in Python 3 ?

Answer (score 0):

I have used openpyxl.  I find it very powerful.  If you are familiar with VBA, you will see a lot of similarities between the syntax and functions used with openpyxl.  THere is also descent (but not great) documentation.  http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html.  You can install openpyxl with pip install too.

Comment: Do you have a sample code to write the values and get formula cell values  in openpyxl ? I tried but its not working . Value comes as 'None' . though the excel file I had saved after inputting values , has formula cell calculated values.